# Where can I find an implementation that uses DFA's to search regular expressions in a text?

Tags: regex, search, dfa

I've already found how to generate the DFA. I want to know which algorithms use DFA's to search regular expressions and if there are any implementations. Thank you!

Comment: Executing a DFA is a quite trivial algorithm, I'm not even sure whether it has an own name?

Comment: I'm a newbie regarding DFA's and I don't know exactly how to use to them to search a given pattern in a text.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton, or maybe some CS textbook?

Comment: I did some research and I understood the mathemathical concepts, I also generated a DFA from a regular expression. The only thing I would like to know is just how to use that DFA to search.

Comment: Basically you just loop over your input string, trying to start the DFA at each index. When a matching attempt succeeds, return that index.

Comment: Of course, there are also a few optimisation strategies for avoiding backtracking, like those known from NFAs. You would treat your search as one NFA, built from your DFA by attaching an extra state at the start that accepts any number of any characters before matching your actual search DFA.

Comment: Are you looking for an engine, or wanting to write one? Most engines use a hybrid nfa/dfa strategy.

Comment: Wanting to write one.

Comment: http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html will be a very good start imho

Comment: Is there any regex library that would give an O(n * m) where m = 1 always and it is independent from the string input size?